# How to align the user name at the center of the profile pic in the same row if the text is too long

Tags: css, react-native, styles

I need to align the text at center of the profile pic in the same line. But it move below the profile pic.

How can I achieve this?

```
<TouchableOpacity >
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginLeft: "8%", marginBottom:"5%",marginRight:"15%",}}>
        <FastImage source={user.profilePicture} style={{width: 45, height: 45, borderRadius: 22.5}}/>
        <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Heebo-Light', fontSize:12, marginLeft:"1.5%",textAlign:'center' }}> { user.firstName } </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to wrap your text in another View with `justifyContent: 'center'` and the same height as your userIcon. Additionally, I changed the `textAlign` to 'left'

**Complete Code:**

```
<TouchableOpacity >
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginLeft: "8%", marginBottom:"5%",marginRight:"15%",}}>
  <Image source={{ uri: 'https://ra.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/user-icon-placeholder.png' }} style={{width: 45, height: 45, borderRadius: 22.5}}/>
    // Adding this View 
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', height: 45}}>
       // changed textAlign to left
      <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Heebo-Light', fontSize:12, marginLeft:"1.5%",textAlign:'left' }}> Usernamed asdfklshfgkjdhgkjdfhgjk dfhljkghdfjkghfdjkgfhfjk ghsdflkaslödsfsdfdsgdkasälöjda skldjsa  </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Working Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/vengeful-sandwich

### Updated Version

We add another View around the Image component and we are removing the height limitation, so that all of our text is visible and the container increases depending on the text content.

**Code:**

```
      <TouchableOpacity >
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginLeft: "8%", marginBottom:"5%",marginRight:"15%",}}>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Image source={{ uri: 'https://ra.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/user-icon-placeholder.png' }} style={{width: 45, height: 45, borderRadius: 22.5}}/>
        </View>
          <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'Heebo-Light', fontSize:12, marginLeft:"1.5%",textAlign:'left' }}> Usernamed asdfklshfgkjdhgkjdfhgjk dfhljkghdfjkghfdjkgfhfjk ghsdflkaslödsfsdfdsgdkasälöjda skldjsa  dasfsdkhf,jdshfkjdshfkjhdsjkfh TEST ETST fdsfgmd,gndfjghjdfkhg dfkghkjdfhgjkdf gkjdfhgjdf gkjdfhg fdg </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

**Output:**

[image: output2]

Comment: It worked for me but the text not wrapped. Some of the text gets hidden